# Comparing monotone functions and their integrals.

Tags: real-analysis

Given two monotone functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x) > g(x)$ over $[0, +\infty)$, is $\int_0^{+\infty} f > \int_0^{+\infty} g$? (Assume both functions, and their integrals, are well-behaved.)

I cannot offhand think of a counterexample, but I also cannot think of a proof of this; either admission may mark me as dense {sigh}.

I ask this, because in working through Bartle & Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis* (4th Ed), one of the answers to a question in Section 8.3 ("Sequences of Functions") appears to depend on the answer to my question being "YES", at least under circumstances that capture this problem (#5c).

If the answer is "YES", but only under certain conditions, what is the weaker statement (ie: what are those conditions)?  I may have missed this in previous chapters, but I've looked and could not find a theorem that seemed to say this.

[And yes, this is a perfect question to pose to a TA or Prof; neither of which I have...{sigh again}.]

TIA!

Comment: $f$ and $g$ need not be monotonous and this still holds

Comment: Copy.  And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)>0$, hence its integral is positive.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!

(Also, thanks to those that demonstrated how I can use the built-in characters to make my questions more readable.)